# Getting a windows-rs HWND from winit?

Tags: rust, winit

I'm fairly new to Rust and am trying to get the following to work:

```
 let hwnd : *mut HWND = window.hwnd().cast();
 let swapchain = unsafe { factory.CreateSwapChainForHwnd(&device, *hwnd, &desc, std::ptr::null(), &output)? } ;
```

where `window.hwnd()` returns a `*mut c_void` and I need to cast that to a `windows::Windows::Win32::Foundation::HWND` , but this example crashes on a access violation. I assume its because I deref a pointer to a `HWND` whereas the `HWND` itself should be the void ptr. `HWND` can be created from an `isize`, so like `HWND(isize)` but I'm not sure if that should get the address of the void pointer or something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you need to convert the pointer to an `isize`, so although this clashes with [recent developments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228) regarding pointer provenance, I believe the correct way to construct an `HWND` is as follows:

```rs
let hwnd = HWND(window.hwnd() as isize);
```

`isize` and `usize` are defined to be pointer width, so converting a raw pointer to one of these types is zero cost and essentially just erases type information.

Note this works because `HWND` is just a newtype struct whose single field is a `pub isize`, so the `HWND(val)` syntax just initializes the struct with that field set to `val`. To access that field you can just do `my_hwnd.0`, and convert to a pointer via `my_hwnd.0 as *mut T`.